# subsetting a dataframe by columnames which are dates

Tags: r, date, dataframe, subset

I would like to subset a `data.frame` based on the dates in the rownames. My dates are of this format:

```
192707
192708
192709

df$Date <- as.yearmon(as.character(df$Date), "%Y%m")
```

edit: I set the rownames equal to the Date variabel like this (and would like to delete Date afterwards):

```
rownames(df)<-df$Date
```

I thought of subsetting like this:

```
 train_dates <- seq(as.yearmon(as.character("1959-12-31"), "%Y%m"), as.yearmon(as.character("1984-12-31"), "%Y%m", "months"))
 df <- subset(df, rownames(df) %in% train_dates)
```

or

```
 df[train_dates,]
```

But I am having difficulties creating the correct sequence.

Comment: I would go for making a column out of your rownames, then subsetting is easily done with lubridate package

Comment: I am trying to avoid that actually. I actually created the rownames from an existing column and I would like to get rid of that date column because I have to filter it out every time I am doing some computation with the rest of the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `format`

```
 train_dates <- format(seq(as.Date.character('1959-01-31'),
                       as.Date.character('1959-12-31'), by = 'month'), '%Y%m')
```

and then, using `library(data.table)`

```
df <- as.data.table(df)    
train_df <- df[Date %in% train_dates]
```

Comment: This does not work somehow, as the datatable is empty. Is it possible that my dates are different? Because printing out my dates from the dataframe rownames: print(rownames(df)), gives me this:
 "Mar 1959" "Apr 1959" "May 1959" "Jun 1959" etc

Comment: But printing train_dates gives me this: "195901" "195903" "195903" "195905"

Comment: So after changing train_dates the same way it worked:

Comment: train_dates <-as.yearmon(as.character(train_dates), "%Y%m")

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be using `rownames_to_column` from `tibble` package.

```
  #data
  df <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = letters[1:5])
  rownames(df) <- c("195901", "196008", "196109", "201812", "196112")
  #        A B
  # 195901 1 a
  # 196008 2 b
  # 196109 3 c
  # 201812 4 d   # not in train_dates
  # 196112 5 e  

  library(zoo)
  #create sequence from 1959 to 1968. Lookup table
  train_dates <- format(as.yearmon(1959 + seq(0, 119)/12), format="%Y%m")
```

**Option #1:**

```
  library(tidyverse)

  df %>%
    rownames_to_column("datemon") %>%
    filter(datemon %in% train_dates) %>%
    column_to_rownames("datemon")

  #        A B
  # 195901 1 a
  # 196008 2 b
  # 196109 3 c
  # 196112 5 e
```

**Option #2**

```
  df[rownames(df) %in% train_dates, ]
  #        A B
  # 195901 1 a
  # 196008 2 b
  # 196109 3 c
  # 196112 5 e
```

Comment: Also very nice, I will add it to my personal cheat sheet!!

Comment: @NiccolaTartaglia Thanks! But I prefer the base-R version which I have added as Option#2. Initially I thought you were looking for options in different way for which I had added Option#1.